# Find p-value? Multiple regression analysis

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, regression-analysis, linear-regression

I want to know can I find the approximate p-value for (beta)2 if you were to test a hypothesis? How do I do that?

\begin{align}
n & = 30 \\
\hat y & = 123.2 + 4.59x_1 + 1.25x_2 − 6.04x_3 \\
sb_0 & = 103.2 \\
sb_1 & = 2.13 \\
sb_2 & = 0.61 \\
sb_3 & = 4.17 \\
R^2 & = 0.47 \\
̅2 = 0.45
\end{align}

These are the options for different p-values. The correct answer is A but I don't know how to get to that conclusion from this information.

A) 0,025
B) 0,05
C) 0,10
D) 0,25
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm guessing the things you denoted $sb_0$, etc. might actually be $s_{b_0}$, i.e. standard error of estimation of the parameter $b_0$, and I'm further guessing that $b_0$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ are supposed to be the coefficients of $1$, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ respectively.  And presume by $R2$ you mean $R^2$.  But I don't know what $\bar{R_2}$ is supposed to be. $\qquad$

Comment: Your notation alone is not enough to present a clear problem.  If $n = 30$ describes the number of datapoints, and you are performing a linear fit of measured $y$ values to sampled $x$ values, then the issue of whether you can carry out the regression seems to have been settled by something you've already done.  On the other hand you may be asking what confidence you should have in the resulting polynomial fit.  Please clarify your Question, and in future consider using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to include mathematical expressions in posts.

Comment: Is your null hypothesis simply that all of the slopes are $0$? $\qquad$

Comment: I think possible the value of $R^2$, the sample size, and the number of predictors (three in this case) might be enough to settle the matter.  I'm not completely sure my guess as to the meaning of the question is right. $\qquad$

Comment: @hardmath I missed out on some crucial detail, does it make sense now?